# How to show the corresponding value of an object in a text field when a value from a dropdown is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have a form in ruby on rails that has a dropdown that contains different category names.

```
<td>
    <div class="div1">
        <%= f.collection_select(:category_id, Category.all, :name, id: 'category_select', :include_blank => '---select waste category---') %>
    </div>
</td>
```

and a text field that should show the category code of the selected category.

```
<td colspan="4"><%= f.text_field :category_id, id: 'name_text_field' %></td>
```

This the table where i get the datas:

```
mysql> desc categories;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| parent_id  | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| code       | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| name       | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

and this is the table where im going to send the data,where my form is intended to:

```
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| quantity      | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| category_id   | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| package_id    | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| created_at    | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at    | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Can anyone help me how to make the corresponding category code appear on the textbox when i select a category name from the dropbox?

Thanks very much in advance!!!

Comment: You will have to bind `change` event to first select box and set the value of other select box in its callback. Please try that and let us know what problems you face.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this. I think there is a typo in your collection_set. Use the following code

```
<%= f.collection_select(:category_id, Category.all, :id, :name, {:include_blank => '---select waste category---'}, {id: 'category_select', onchange: "$('#name_text_field').val(this.options[this.selectedIndex].innerHTML);"}) %>
```

This will show the Category name in the textbox on selecting something from the dropdown.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for your help Gowtham, but it stll doesnt show anything on the textfield when i select from the drop down.

Comment: @PhilipJayFernandez do you see any error in the browser console when you select something from the dropdown? (You can open browser console by pressing F12). Also your text field HTML attribute id is name_text_field right as per your question

Answer (score 0):

I managed to have a solution for my problem thanks for gowtham's idea

this is what i did:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $("#category_id").on("change", function() {
    $("#code_textfield").val($("#_category_id").val());
  });
});
</script>
```

for my text field:

```
<%= f.text_field :category_id, :id => "code_textfield" %>
```

and for my dropbox:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:category_id, Category.all, :code,:name, :include_blank => '---select waste category---') %>
```